# изменить изображение пина в MKMapView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, карты

Я пытаюсь изменить изображение пина на карте на картинку. Но как бы я не пытался пин так и продолжает выглядеть обыкновенной булавкой. Мой код

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {
        return nil;
    }
    static NSString* identifier = @"Annotation";

    MKPinAnnotationView* pin = (MKPinAnnotationView*)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (!pin) {
        pin = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
        pin.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"хххх"];
        pin.animatesDrop = YES;
        pin.canShowCallout = YES;
        pin.draggable = YES; 
    } else {
        pin.annotation = annotation;
    }
    return pin;
}
```

что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1):

Замените Ваш `MKPinAnnotationView` на `MKAnnotationView`.

Comment: спасибо, заработало